# how to remove elements added in a string with event.unicode in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, python-unicode

I have a function in my program so that the player can type his name that will then appear on the screen. But is there a way so when the player hit the backspace key for example, the last letter added to the string is removed ?

Heres the function, I don't think I need to write the rest of the code concerning the name of the player :

```
def enter_player_name(self):
    player_name_screen = True
    while player_name_screen:
        win.blit(playerNameImg[self.namecount//1], (self.x_0, self.y_0))
        self.namecount += 1
        if (self.namecount + 1) >= 8:
            self.namecount = 0
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
                    print(self.name)
                    player_name_screen = False
                    self.display = GAME_SCREEN
                else:
                    self.name += event.unicode
                    self.text_name = game_font.render(self.name, True, BLANC)
        win.blit(self.text_name, (500, 500))
        pg.display.update()
```

Thanks for you help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last character of the text (`self.name = self.name[:-1]`) when the backspace key is pressed and render the new text:

```py
if event.key == pg.K_RETURN:
    print(self.name)
    player_name_screen = False
    self.display = GAME_SCREEN

elif event.key == pg.K_BACKSPACE:
    self.name = self.name[:-1]
    self.text_name = game_font.render(self.name, True, BLANC)

else:
    self.name += event.unicode
    self.text_name = game_font.render(self.name, True, BLANC)
```